# Debian update broke drivers and terminal

Tags: terminal, wifi, drivers

I'm new to Linux. I've been using it since Debian 12 Bookworm came out. I was able to compile the drivers for my USB wireless dongle, and it was installed and working. My operating system has been stable since I installed it in July. I've been careful with the updates to apps and the OS.

Today I received a notification for updates. I checked that there were several updates to the NVIDIA driver and Debia12u1 which I assume was a stable update as well as clang 17 and other compilers. I updated and everything went fine, but my wireless USB stopped working, not being recognized again.

I just went to the folder with the driver, recompiled and installed it again. The WiFi didn't work. The terminal also stopped working. It stays blank loading.

WiFi adapter driver: RTL8811CU
Package manager wrapper: nala
Shell wrapper: synth

I don't know what to do:

- How do I recover my terminal?
- How do I uninstall/reinstall all the drivers without using the terminal?
- How do I revert the update (is there a remote chance?)?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the TTY by CTL + Alt + F3 then remove Nala, reinstall the default debian terminal.

There is no problem with the debian updates. To install the WiFi driver use the dkms way from this git [repository](https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU).

Comment: I was able to recover access to the terminal via TTY but it also hangs. So I removed the USB dongle, removed the driver via DKMS and now I have control back, but everytime I reinstall the USB wifi driver it is sucessful but then the machine hangs. I'll unbolt this machine from the rack and take it to a RJ45 cable near so that I can pull the driver git again as a last effort but I don't understand why the driver was touched. Thank you for the insights I'm still a bit lost but I'll try to rebuild the drivers again and understand why it is failing. The Dongle works when I switch to Windows.

Comment: @TiagoMatos  You're forgetting something here: In Windows the driver for your dongle is a static binary blob, i.e. it was compiled once and will work until the manufacturer updates it.  In all linux'es kernel modules must be version matched.  Try `uname -a` in a terminal, take note of the kernel version, and verify whether or not you need to compile a newer module.

Comment: Hello @eyoung100 yes It took me a bit to understand that so I tried to recompile and no joy. It recompiles installs and detects but then It can't connect. I'm buying a friendlier Wifi Dongle with Linux.